# Liferay using http and https

Tags: ssl, https, liferay, liferay-6

I'm trying to use Liferay for http and https

if I include in portal-ext.properties:

```
company.security.auth.requires.https=true
web.server.protocol=https
```

Will be working ok with https but in http is showing incorrect themes due is trying to load https://domain.com/theme

If I remove this two lines is working ok for http but not for https.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO mixed mode, e.g. offering http as well as https never gives you what you expect: You expect security from https, but you always risk leaking session information, e.g. being vulnerable to session-hijacking attacks (ala Firesheep). My actual advice would be to go [https only](https://www.liferay.com/de/marketplace/-/mp/application/27551660) if you do https for security. Read on if that's not an option for you, but don't complain when you find information leaking (this is not dependent on Liferay, but for any web-based environment)

What is the exact problem that you have with the themes? (images/css through http?)  Which version of Liferay are you using?

Before you specify more, you might want to configure your theme's "virtual path", this will rewrite all the URLs referring to your theme. It's typically used to serve static resources through a webserver or cdn, but it works with any kind of URL. Simply using a protocol-relative URL should work (I love this mostly unknown http feature):

Add this to your theme's liferay-look-and-feel.xml:

```
 <look-and-feel>
    <theme id="my" name="My Theme">
       <virtual-path>//domain.com/myTheme</virtual-path>
    </theme>
 </look-and-feel>
```

note that the URL omits the protocol part, `http:` or `https:`, thus the browser will use the same protocol that the whole page is loaded with.

Edit: corrected the xml. Will investigate if there's a problem with protocol-relative URLs in themes.

Edit 2: Something is weird. It seems, virtual-path does not work like this, but I recall it did earlier. Do you add domain.com as cdn.host.http or cdn.host.https? (this would be concatenated)

On related stuff, please check if you're running Apache in front of your appserver. In this case you might forward some traffic for the portal (e.g. in the virtual host for http) but not forward the traffic in the https virtual host.

Comment: Yes, I can't access to css, fonts, images, etc. I'm using Liferay 6.1.1. If I add //domain.com/myTheme . The path of the css is http://domain.com/domain.com/myTheme. If I use /myTheme is not working as well.